# Dumping data into Excel from C# using set_Value throws an error

Tags: excel, c#-2.0, excel-interop

I am trying to dump data into an Excel file. The following is the code we use.

Note: dt is a DataTable passed from another function.

```
        ApplicationClass xlsApp = new ApplicationClass();
        WorkbookClass xlsWb = null;
        Worksheet xlsWs = null;
        Range ExcelCellText;

        try
        {
            xlsWb = (WorkbookClass)xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\WorkingFolder\Code\EnVazhi2.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlsWs = (Worksheet)xlsWb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            ExcelCellText = xlsWs.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
            ExcelCellText = ExcelCellText.get_Resize(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count);
            string[,] myArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];

            int iRow=0;

            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dt.Columns.Count; iCol++)
                {
                    myArray[iRow, iCol] = dr[iCol].ToString();
                }
                iRow++;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); 
            ExcelCellText.set_Value(Missing.Value, myArray);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

It throws the exception

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

at the line

```
            ExcelCellText.set_Value(Missing.Value, myArray);
```

The Excel file is partly populated. The exception happens when it tries to copy this value from myArray into the Excel.

> Enawvg Xnhe/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr  10-02-2009
>   09:39 NZ       Gb PPEC/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr@ZnkArjLbexYvsr
>   pp
>
> Fhowrpg Sj: cyf vagvngr ershaq
>
> Uv,
>
> cyrnfr svaq gur pbeerpg cbyvpl ahzore
>
> 268538840
>
> Enawvg Xnhe
>
> ----- Sbejneqrq ol Enawvg Xnhe/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr ba 02/10/2009
>   09:38 NZ ----- PPEC/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr 02/09/2009 05:37
>   CZ       Gb Enawvg
>   Xnhe/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr@ZnkArjLbexYvsr
>   pp
>
> Fhowrpg Er: cyf vagvngr ershaq
>
> Uv
>
> Gunax lbh sbe jevgvat gb Phfgbzre
>   Freivprf ng Znk Arj Lbex Yvsr
>   Vafhenapr.
>
> Jr npxabjyrqtr gur erprvcg bs lbhe
>   inyhnoyr srrqonpx naq bhe Phfgbzre
>   Freivpr Rkrphgvir jvyy trg va gbhpu
>   jvgu lbh va gur arkg 48 ubhef.
>
> Cyrnfr abgr gung gur ersrerapr ahzore
>   sbe lbhe srrqonpx ner
>
> 268538295 2141982 268598840 vapbeerpg
>   ab.
>
> Jr erdhrfg lbh gb dhbgr gur nobir
>   ahzore va nyy shgher pbzzhavpngvba
>   jvgu ZALY ercerfragngvirf.
>
> Lbh znl nyfb trg va gbhpu jvgu bhe
>   Phfgbzre Uryc Yvar ahzore 1800 180
>   5577 (gbyy serr vs pnyyvat sebz ZGAY
>   be OFAY argjbex) be 0124-2542001
>
> Gunaxf naq Ertneqf Xnenz Fvatu
>   Phfgbzre Freivprf Znk Arj Lbex Yvsr
>   Vafhenapr Pb. Ygq. Bcrengvba Pragre,
>   Cybg Ab. - 90 N Frpgbe - 18, Hqlbt
>   Ivune Thetnba - 122002 Gry - 0124 -
>   2542001 Gbyy Serr - 1800-180-5577 Snk
>   ahzore -- 0124 - 4239683
>
> Enawvg Xnhe/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr  09-02-2009
>   03:07 CZ       Gb PPEC/Bcrengvbaf/Ubzr
>   Bssvpr/ZnkArjLbexYvsr@ZnkArjLbexYvsr
>   pp
>
> Fhowrpg cyf vagvngr ershaq
>
> Uv,
>
> cyf ybt n serfu pnfr
>
> ershaq purdhr abg erprvirq
>
> 268538295 268598840
>
> Enawvg Xnhe

Why does it throw an error? Is there a known issue with set_Value?

I tried the following two options described here at [Link 1](http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15)

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

This code works perfectly fine when I use Microsoft Office Excel 2007 SP 2.

The version/SP of Microsoft Office Excel 2003 where it fails is this the Standard Release (with NO SP's installed).

Comment: What version (and SP) of Excel? I believe there is a ~1000 character limit/bug on older versions but not sure which version/SP it was fixed in.

Comment: @ktharsis: Thanks for the update. It is Office 2003, I am not sure of the SP as I will go into work tomorrow to find that out. But, I am glad that you *believe* that there was a fix for the 1000 character bug! Phew. Wipes sweat of forehead. I owe you one.

Comment: Not sure how to find the SP. But, the version number as listed in the About box is this - 11.5612.5606

Comment: @ktharsis: I tested the code even on SP3 and it still failed. I think it works fine only with Office 2007 and not before :-(

Comment: Think it is an Excel "feature" (bug). One of the 2003 SPs might fix it. Also saw refs to it on expert exchange but don't have an account there so can't find the answers. You can try using set_value only on the single cell (instead of range/array) and see if that will work around the issue.

Comment: @ktharsis: The reference to Expert Exchange was spotted. But in the link they provided, they say you can do **nothing** about it. See here for the article. http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003163_Character_Limits_for_Cells.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have run up on a limitation of Excel itself. So the [unfortunate] answer to your question is yes - there is a known issue with set_value. The best workaround is to check to see if the user has a minimum version of Excel and react accordingly (don't run, truncate to 1000 chars, split the text across multiple fields, skip those cells, etc).

Probably not what you wanted to find out. I wrote this as an answer instead of continuing the comment trail but feel free to write and accept your own answer.

Comment: I don't think, I could have written it any better!